# Find consecutive rows of a 2D array with maximum number of 1s

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic-programming

I have 2D array of size `m*m` with element values either 0s or 1s. Furthermore, each column of the array has a contiguous block of 1s (with 0 outside that block). The array itself is too large to be held in memory (as many as 10^6 rows), but for each column I can determine the lower bound, `a`, and the upper bound, `b`, of the 1s in that column. For a given `n`, I need to find out those `n` consecutive rows which have the maximum number of 1s. I can easily do it for smaller numbers by calculating the sum of each row one by one, and then choosing `n` consecutive rows whose sum comes out to be maximum, but for large numbers, it is consuming too much time. Is there any efficient way for calculating this? Perhaps using Dynamic Programming?

Here is an example code fragment showing my current approach, where successive calls to `read_int()` (not given here) provide the lower and upper bounds for successive columns:

```
   long int harr[10000]={0};       //initialized to zero
   for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
        a=read_int();
        b=read_int();
        for(int j=a;j<=b;j++)        // for finding sum of each row
           harr[j]++;
    }
   answer=0;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        answer=answer+harr[i];
    }
    current=answer;
    for(int i=n;i<m;i++)
    {
        current=current+harr[i]-harr[i-n];
        if(current>answer)
        {
            answer=current;
        }
    }
```

For example (with `m` = 6 and `n` = 3)

[image]

Here the answer would be row 1 to row 3 with a total 1-count of 13 in those rows. (Row 2 to row 4 also maximizes the sum as there is a tie.)

Comment: what do you mean by maximum number of 1s? Can you please include one of your smaller examples so we can see it?

Comment: So `n` is an imput parameter with `n <=m`?

Comment: There's no way to avoid calculating the sum of each row. Since you must be reading the inputs from somewhere, you can compute the sums while reading, and store the results in a 1D array of size `m`. As for the rest of it, please post the code that you've already tried, and give an example of input and output.

Comment: You can easily calculate for first `i` column which rows has the maximum number of 1s, as you iterate i from 0 to the end, you will discover some rows has no hope to catch up with the current maximum. Worst case (all 1s or all 0s everywhere) does not improve. Best case you can cut the time by half.

Comment: So the right path to go is to massively parallelize the code using OpenMP/OpenCL/CUDA

Comment: @JohnColeman The code that was added to the question indicates that it's not a 2D array at all, but a series of (potentially overlapping) intervals. So the input is actually `m` intervals given as `{start,end}`. And it's still unclear as to what the output is supposed to be. Still waiting for an example of input and output...

Comment: You should edit your question. As user3386109 points out, this has little to do with 2D arrays. Instead -- it seems more like you are trying to find a range in a histogram which is as large as possible.

Comment: Given your recent edits -- I don't see anything inefficient in the way you determine `answer` from `harr`. That is linear in the number of rows and even with 10^6 rows (instead of the 10000 in your code sample) that part of the computation will run in a fraction of a second. I suspect that any attempt to continually update a tentative `answer` while loading `harr` would be counter-productive. Are you sure that `read_int()` isn't your bottleneck?

Comment: I'm out of time, so I have to be brief. The problem is in the first `for` loop. If `m` is 1M and a typical difference between `a` and `b` is 50K, then the first loop executes 50 billion times. So you need to read all of the intervals, sort the `a` values, sort the `b` values, and then do your processing directly on the sorted lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a different approach. Think of each pair `a`, `b` as defining an interval of the form [a,b+1). The task is to find the `n` consecutive indices which maximizes the sum of the *parenthesis depth* of the numbers in that interval. Every new `a` bumps the parenthesis depth at `a` up by 1. Every new `b` causes the parenthesis depth *after* `b` to go down by 1. In the first pass -- just load these parentheses depth deltas. Then one pass gets the parenthesis depths from these deltas. The following code illustrates this approach. I reduced `m` to 6 for testing purposes and replaced calls to the unkown `read_int()` by accesses to hard-wired arrays (which correspond to the example in the question):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int a,b,answer,current,lower,upper;
    int n = 3;
    int lower_bound[6] = {0,1,2,3,1,2};
    int upper_bound[6] = {3,4,3,5,2,4};
    int m = 6;
    int harr[6]={0};

    //load parenthesis depth-deltas (all initially 0)
       for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
        {
            a = lower_bound[i];
            b = upper_bound[i];
            harr[a]++;
            if(b < m-1)harr[b+1]--;
        }

    //determine p-depth at each point
        for(int i = 1; i < m; i++){
            harr[i] += harr[i-1];
        }

    //find optimal n-rows by sliding-window
       answer = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            answer = answer+harr[i];
        }
        current  =answer;
        lower = 0;
        upper = n-1;

        for(int i=n;i<m;i++)
        {
            current = current+harr[i]-harr[i-n];
            if(current>answer)
            {
                answer = current;
                lower = i-n+1;
                upper = i;
            }
        }
    printf("Max %d rows are %d to %d with a total sum of %d ones\n", n,lower,upper,answer);
    return 0;
}
```

(Obviously, the loop which loads `harr` can be combined with the loop which computes `answer`. I kept it as two passes to better illustrate the logic of how the final `harr` values can be obtained from the parentheses deltas).

When this code is compiled and run its output is:

```
Max 3 rows are 1 to 3 with a total sum of 13 ones
```

Comment: Thats what i have implemented but i need to do it for 10^6 rows which is too much time consuming.

Comment: If you have a non-sparse matrix (of 4 terabytes?) I don't see how you could do much better. If it is sparse -- how are you representing the data?

Comment: actually i m provided with the range for every column and i need to set every element to 1 there and then i need to find out the n consecutive rows which are having maximum sum. So instead of such a large array i am just incrementing the values in some other array.

Comment: @abcdfndjdnkn Now that I understand your problem -- I think that it is possible to do it fairly efficiently. See if this new answer works. It got rid of that inner loop in your example code.

Comment: @John Coleman What is a and what is b? It is an awful code of a man who is unable to write programs.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow The code in the answer was never meant to be a free-standing program but instead is a modification of a code fragment from OP's question. In context of the question, `a`, `b` are integers which satisfy the inequality `0 <= a <= b < m` (where `m` = 10,000 in the sample code). There was a somewhat destructive edit (not by OP) in the hours after I answered -- in particular someone deleted a diagram which illustrated the meaning of `a` and `b`. I rolled back that particular edit.

Comment: @John Coleman  The problem is that your answer is read by others and they should understand the code you showed.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow You are doubtless correct. On the other hand, it is common to interpret an answer to a question in terms of the context of the question. You could fault OP for not including a self-contained program if you want, but it seems odd to criticize me for first understanding what their question was and then answering it to their satisfaction by showing how to modify the code fragment that they actually provided. Still, you do have a good point. I'll edit my question by providing a sample definition of `read_int()` (which seems to depend on some global state) and a `main` function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how the following will scale for your `10^6` rows, but it manages the the trailing sum of `x` consecutive rows in a single pass without function call overhead. It may be worth a try. Also insure you are compiling with full optimizations so the compiler can add its 2 cents as well.

My original thought was to find some way to read `x` * `n` integers (from your `m x n` matrix) and in some fashion look at a population of set bits over that number of bytes. (checking the endianness) and taking either the first or last byte for each integer to check whether a bit was set. However, the logic seemed as costly as simply carrying the sum of the trailing `x` rows and stepping through the array while attempting to optimize the logic.

I don't have any benchmarks from your data to compare against, but perhaps this will give you another idea or two.:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#ifndef CHAR_BIT
#define CHAR_BIT  8
#endif

#ifndef INT_MIN
#define INT_MIN -(1U << (sizeof (int) * CHAR_BIT - 1))
#endif

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    /* number of consecutive rows to sum */
    size_t ncr = argc > 1 ? (size_t)atoi (argv[1]) : 3;

    /* static array to test summing and row id logic, not
       intended to simulate the 0's or 1's */
    int a[][5] = {{1,2,3,4,5},
                  {2,3,4,5,6},
                  {3,4,5,6,7},
                  {4,5,6,7,8},
                  {3,4,5,6,7},
                  {0,1,2,3,4},
                  {1,2,3,4,5}};
    int sum[ncr];               /* array holding sum on ncr rows */
    int sumn = 0;               /* sum of array values */
    int max = INT_MIN;          /* variable holding maximum sum  */
    size_t m, n, i, j, k, row = 0, sidx;

    m = sizeof  a / sizeof *a;  /* matrix m x n dimensions */
    n = sizeof *a / sizeof **a;

    for (k = 0; k < ncr; k++)   /* initialize vla values */
        sum[k] = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)     /* for each row */
    {
        sidx = i % ncr;         /* index for sum array */

        if (i > ncr - 1) {      /* sum for ncr prior rows */
            for (k = 0; k < ncr; k++)
                sumn += sum[k];
            /* note 'row' index assignment below is 1 greater
               than actual but simplifies output loop indexes */
            max = sumn > max ? row = i, sumn : max;
            sum[sidx] = sumn = 0; /* zero index to be replaced and sumn */
        }

        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) /* compute sum for current row */
            sum [sidx] += a[i][j];
    }

    /* output results */
    printf ("\n The maximum sum for %zu consecutive rows: %d\n\n", ncr, max);

    for (i = row - ncr; i < row; i++) {
        printf (" row[%zu] : ", i);
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            printf (" %d", a[i][j]);
        printf ("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Output**

```
$./bin/arraymaxn

 The maximum sum for 3 consecutive rows: 80

 row[2] :  3 4 5 6 7
 row[3] :  4 5 6 7 8
 row[4] :  3 4 5 6 7

$./bin/arraymaxn 4

 The maximum sum for 4 consecutive rows: 100

 row[1] :  2 3 4 5 6
 row[2] :  3 4 5 6 7
 row[3] :  4 5 6 7 8
 row[4] :  3 4 5 6 7

$ ./bin/arraymaxn 2

 The maximum sum for 2 consecutive rows: 55

 row[2] :  3 4 5 6 7
 row[3] :  4 5 6 7 8
```

**Note:** if there are multiple equivalent maximum consecutive rows (i.e. two sets of rows where the 1's add up the the same number), the first occurrence of the maximum is selected.

I'm not sure what optimizations you are choosing to compile with, but regardless which code you use, you can always try the simple hints to the compiler to inline all functions (if you have functions in your code) and fully optimize the code. Two helpful ones are:

```
gcc -finline-functions -Ofast
```